# SQL | Convert Google Map URL to Lag and Lng

Tags: mysql, sql, google-maps

In my phpmyadmin SQL database, I have hundreds of Google map URLs. I want to change them into lat and lng automatically.

For example:

```
http://maps.google.com.hk/maps?f=q&source=embed&hl=zh-TW&geocode;=&q=軒尼詩道+438+號&aq;=&sll=22.279427,114.181616&sspn=0.012191,0.016544&brcurrent=3,0x34040055b36dac7f:0x23fa8b1e7120c6a,0,0x3404004c435d4ad9:0x6e0e524894ae1a66&ie=UTF8&hq;=&hnear;=軒尼詩道438號&ll=22.279429,114.181622&spn=0.000496,0.000587&z=19&iwloc=A
```

How can I write a SQL instruction to extract lat and lng out of it?
All lat and lng are after `&ll=`
In the example:

```
&ll=22.279429,114.181622
```

How can I write a SQL script to search digits only after `&ll`?

Comment: I think you should parse the url with php methods: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: It depends. Which database you are using? mysql? postgres? mssql? etc. Please post which one

Comment: I am using mysql. I have made the table three columns, one is google URL, the another two are lat and lng. I would like to extract the lat and lng from google URL by running SQL query in phpMyadmin. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may look a little hairy but should give you what you need in the example. See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/618f9/8). Will leave the additional cases where the `ll` parameter occurs straight after the `?` in the URL or is the last parameter in the list as exercises for the reader :-)

```
SELECT url,
       SUBSTRING(url,
                 LOCATE('&ll=', url) + 4,
                 LOCATE(',', url, LOCATE('&ll=', url)) - 
                     (LOCATE('&ll=', url) + 4)) AS lat,
       SUBSTRING(url,
                 LOCATE(',', url, LOCATE('&ll=', url)) + 1,
                 LOCATE('&', url, LOCATE(',', url, LOCATE('&ll=', url))) - 
                     (LOCATE(',', url, LOCATE('&ll=', url)) + 1)) AS lng
FROM mapurls
```